# Permission denied while executing shell script

Tags: shell, file, permissions

i have one command in shell script which counts number of lines in file and if they are zero then continue to execute rest of the script.

*Example :*

```
v_cnt=`wc -l $1/test_$3.bad`
if v_cnt > 0
then
    exit 1
fi
```

File gets generate dynamically.

issue i am facing is , when file does not get generated , i get Permission denied  error. However it works properly when file is present. please help me for the same.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. Your first statement says "if they are non zero, then continue to execute rest of the script", but in your example, you `exit 1` when the count is greater than 0. Also, `$1/test_$3.bad` is the file that's getting generated? If so how is it getting generated? Show us more/full code.

Comment: sorry for the typo, please consider this,  if they are non zero then *exit* else execute rest of the script. Also, file is getting generated by another application.

Comment: What version of unix/linux are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server , VERSION=7.2 (Maipo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Rather than using `wc -l`, try using the `else` condition in `if [ -s ]`.

```
if [ -e $1/test_$3.bad ]
then
    if [ -s $1/test_$3.bad ]
    then
        exit 1
    else
        do something
    fi
else
    echo "File was not generated"
fi
```